# Adding lazy=false using annotation in hibernate java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am having below xml mapping file where they have used many-to-one column,

```
  <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.example.offerUser"
         table="offerUser">
      <id name="offerUserId" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="OOFER_USER_ID"/>
        <generator class="identity"/>
      </id>
      <many-to-one name="offer"
        class="com.example.offer"
        fetch="select" lazy="false">
        <column name="OFFER_ID"/>
      </many-to-one> 
      <many-to-one name="user"
        class="com.example.User"
        fetch="select" lazy="false">
        <column name="USER_ID"/>
      </many-to-one> 
        </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and here is annotation code,where i am replacing xml by annotation,but how to replace  lazy="false" in annotation.

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "offerUser")

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class offerUser {


    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "OOFER_USER_ID")  
    private Long offerUserId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)    
    @JoinColumn(name="OFFER_ID")
    private offer offer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)    
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private User user;

}
```

I searched in google,but i they have not mentioned any thing about setting lazy=false, instead they have used 'Optional = false'.Why is it so.?Please help me on this.

Comment: The default is `EAGER` unless otherwise specified.

Comment: So, ^^, in other words is don't put anything for the fetch type or explicitly set it to eager.

Comment: @chrylis i need to set lazy false.How to set that?

Comment: Just remove the `LAZY` argument from the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

In hibernate annotations ( @ManyToOne ) default fetch type is EAGER.